# Anonomous alternative to skype - voip?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, security

I want to use skype, but it is not anonomous enough for me, is there a more anonomous alternative that I could use? I don't want anyone to be able to see my IP, including the other people in the call.
**I deem this question on topic because it is difficult to find one of these just from using a search engine, and the TOR community I would expect would have some info on this**
What I have found so far:
1) Orbot - You can run skype through this on an android, and it is more anonomous, but I don't have an android so this won't work for me.
2) You cannot run voice directly over TOR, because it is too slow.
3) jitsi does not protect you from the other people in the call.
- Also, Video is not necessary, I wont be using it.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, [Mumble](http://mumble.sourceforge.net) is good for this. The only slight problem is that it's based on client-server architecture so, so as best case some of you needs to host it. (Not that complex to setup)

Answer (score 0):

I started Asterisk VoIP server over OpenVPN in Tor hidden service.
It's working with 1s delay.

First create OpenSSL CA with Easy-RSA or OpenSSL for OpenVPN.

This is OpenVPN server configuration file:

```
tls-server
port 1194
proto tcp
dev tun
ca /etc/ssl/ca.crt
cert /etc/ssl/server.crt
key /etc/ssl/server.key
dh /etc/ssl/dh2048.pem
topology subnet
server 10.0.0.0 255.255.0.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
keepalive 10 120
cipher AES-256-CBC
max-clients 100
persist-key
persist-tun
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log
log /var/log/openvpn.log
log-append /var/log/openvpn-append.log
verb 3
auth SHA512
```

This is OpenVPN client configuration file:

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote svntrqfgsa7jgnpm.onion 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca /home/norbert/new/ca.crt
cert /home/norbert/new/demo-alice.crt
key /home/norbert/new/demo-alice.key
cipher AES-256-CBC
auth SHA512
verb 3
socks-proxy 127.0.0.1 9050
remote-cert-tls server
```

This is Asterisk sip.conf configuration file:

```
[general]
transport=udp
port=5060
bindaddr=10.0.0.1
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
allow=gsm
directmedia=no
nat=yes
localnet=10.0.0.0/255.255.0.0

[friends_internal](!)
type=friend
host=dynamic
context=from-internal
disallow=all
allow=ulaw
allow=alaw
allow=gsm

[demo-alice](friends_internal)
secret=password

[demo-bob](friends_internal)
secret=password
```

This is Asterisk extensions.conf configuration file:

```
[from-internal]
exten=>6001,1,Dial(SIP/demo-alice,20)
exten=>6002,1,Dial(SIP/demo-bob,20)
```

This is Tor hidden service server torrc configuration file:

```
HiddenServiceDir /usr/local/torhs/winternight/
HiddenServicePort 1194 127.0.0.1:1194
```

This is Tor client configuration file:

```
SOCKSPort 9050
```

That's all. It's working with 1s delay.

Documented in these tutorials:

- [How To setup Asterisk VoIP server over OpenVPN in Tor hidden service on FreeBSD system](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13595/how-to-setup-asterisk-voip-server-over-openvpn-in-tor-hidden-service-on-freebsd)
- https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/59190/

Enjoy. :)